# Please explain Integer Quantum Hall effect graph

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-hall-effect

[image: Halls resistivity vs Magnetic field]

What are the green spikes in the graph? Are they the energies associated with each quantized Landau level? I am not sure I understand this properly

Comment: Duplicate - [Quantum Hall Effect: Why the spikes of the longitudinal resistance appear every time when Hall conductance jumps?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/476184/quantum-hall-effect-why-the-spikes-of-the-longitudinal-resistance-appear-every)